# Search across all tabs in iTerm2

Tags: search, iterm

Is it possible somehow to search across all open tabs/sessions in iTerm2? I'd like to do something like a regular search (Cmd+F), searching the scrollback buffer, but across everything I have open instead of just the current tab/session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone using iTerm2 3.x, this functionality has been moved to `Edit > Find > Find Globally`

[Source](https://iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html)

Answer (score 9):

[Source](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html):

In a window menu, go to `Windows -> Exposé All Tabs`.  This will show you all open iTerm windows on one screen.

> All iTerm2 tabs will be shown tiled on the main screen. You can mouse over a tab to see it larger, and clicking on it will restore the windows and select that tab and bring its window to the front. **You can search the contents of all tabs by typing in the search field that appears on the left. Making a selection from the results below it will highlight the tab that contains that text.** This is useful when you have many tabs open and can't find the one you're looking for. 
>   [image]